# Unable to Open Open Office spreadsheet on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, openoffice, file-association

It used to work fine a few months ago.  So it must be one of the Win 10 updates.

When I click on the .ods file, Open Office flashes up and then closes.  If I start Open Office from its shortcut on the desktop and select the same file, it works fine.

I have done these things, but no luck.

1. Deleted the Open Office profile
2. Repaired the install.
3. Removed and Re-installed it.

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Try running it from command line. It might show what the error is.

Comment: Could the .ods Windows association be for an older version or something?  A test would be to right-click on the file, choose "Open with" and then "Choose another app" and see if it will open when you choose OpenOffice from that list.

Comment: @Lyrl I tried that already.  I can make Excel open it.  Then I switched it back and Open Office still wont open it.  And as mentioned, I reinstalled Open Office.

Comment: @Alexiy What a clever idea.  When I type the filename.ods in command line, Open Office actually opens like it should.  Tried it again in explorer - it just flashes open and closes.

Comment: Have you ever had LibreOffice installed on this computer?